any way to fix a crumbling foundation hole?
Here's the problem: the house is over a century old and has been renovated and repaired before, I'm not sure how it was built initially, or all of it's repairs (the soil in that corner is awfully sandy and little grows there. likely a hack job by the contractor that last worked on it), but there's a big hole in the foundation, ground level and below. It appears to be built on a pillar like foundation with bricks in between and concrete on top, I base this on the foundation being an even cement on the outside, a large pillar to the right of the hole and crumbled bricks being found while slightly excavating what seemed to be a rat's nest.
I've purvayed similar plights, though none to this extent. Best I've found is to use hydraulic cement and pour it into the hole.
I should note, the soil here's whack. The whole yard's a golf course for rats, pits and valleys galore!
Here are some pictures:



Which property do you want answers for?

probably the one where I went into extensive detail on the problem and posted pictures of

Looks like you're getting some undermining there.  Looks to me like that is the first problem to solve.

If the foundation is pillars supporting a beam (appears to be what you are describing) with brick infill under the beam between pillars, then the pillars are what holds up the beam, and the brick infill area is non-structural.
As such, you can repair it pretty much any way you like. If bricks have crumbled, new bricks and mortar would be a more suitable repair than hydrualic cement, which is more for patching relatively small holes in concrete. Pouring new concrete after cleaning out the hole would be another option.

There are companies that can support the existing foundation, dig out and then create a new supporting foundation.
They also work on sections at a time so that the building stays supported.
Research companies with the experience to do this in your location, as this is not an area of work that DIY repairs which may not take account of all the variables is advised.

My neighbours moved a house onto their lot.  They then dug the foundation hole out under the house.  It did take quite a few weeks to do.  Not a fast job.
